# Extract link from XPath using Selenium Webdriver and Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I'm rather new to Seleniun WebDriver and Python and my question might be kind of basic.

So, I have the following HTML code:

```
<a class="wp-first-item" href="admin.php?page=account">Account</a>
```

And *I am trying to extract the href out of it*, be means of XPath, knowing that its XPath is `".//*[@id='toplevel_page_menu']/ul/li[2]/a"`.

How do I do that?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='toplevel_page_menu']/ul/li[2]/a").link
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='toplevel_page_menu']/ul/li[2]/a").href
```

Do not seem to work, resulting in:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'link'
```

I'm expecting the result to be like `"admin.php?page=account"`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `get_attribute`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='toplevel_page_menu']/ul/li[2]/a")
href = element.get_attribute('href')
print href
```

Ordinarily I use Selenium to navigate to a page, retrieve the source and parse it with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# On the current page
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)

href = soup('<the tag containing the anchor>',{'id':'toplevel_page_menu'})[0]('ul')[0]('li')[2]('a')[0]['href']
```

Unfortunately, BeautifulSoup does not support xpath, so the above is a BS representation of your xpath (as far as I understand it).

Comment: Do I need to import something exotic in order for get_attribute() to work?

Adding /@href at the end does not seem to work.

Comment: try `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='toplevel_page_menu']/ul/li[2]/a")` then using `get_attribute`: `print element.get_attribute('href')`. That might work. I'm sorry for the confusion, I typically don't extract source data via Selenium. Like I said, I usually use BS.